# Help with mechanism similar to Robinson Annulation

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, enolate-chemistry

[image]

I need to figure out a mechanism for this reaction. All I know is that it is supposed to have a similar mechanism to Robinson Annulation.

This is the best I could come up with, but I've been told it is incorrect.

[image]

When trying to correct this, the only thing I could think of is that maybe in the cis configuration the ethoxy group provided too much steric hindrance for the second bond to be formed. In that case, I could have

[image]

I am far from sure about this. Can you guys help point me in the right direction?

Edit:

Apparently the correct mechanism is

[image]

As far as I can tell, I was marked off for not adding and then immediately abstracting a proton at the same position, and I was marked down for this twice. I thought the point of a mechanism was to show the most direct way to reach the product-why would I bother to add a proton to an intermediate, just to take it away the next step, leaving me with the same intermediate, and the same next step? Maybe someone here can explain why my omission is significant.

Comment: Great job!!! There may be an Z to E isomerization as you described. I'd give you an A, if I could! PS: Info on a solvent would have been useful.

Comment: The reason I asked about solvent was that the product is a vinylogous, non-enolic -diketone. Ethoxide can add to the cyclopentanone carbonyl and the fragment then ring to give an ester. Secondly, Chem. Abst. doesn't know about this reaction.

Comment: I don't know the solvent. I assumed it was ethanol because the catalytic base was just showed as EtO-, instead of OH- or something else